# Why the calculation of hash in HashMap(JDK1.8) don't need to consider the negative hashCode as ConcurrentHashMap does?

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

In `HashMap`:  `(h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);`

In `ConcurrentHashMap`: `(h ^ (h >>> 16)) & HASH_BITS;`

where `HASH_BITS` is `0x7fffffff`, by `& HASH_BITS` it can always be a positive number.

Answer (score 2):

> Why the calculation of hash in HashMap(JDK1.8) don't need to consider the negative hashCode as ConcurrentHashMap does?

Ultimately, the case where the hash is negative (after spreading) *does* need to be considered in the `HashMap` case as well.  It is just that this happens later in the code.

For example, in `getNode` (Java 8) you find this:

```
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
```

Since `tab.length` is a power of 2, `tab.length - 1` is a suitable bitmask for reducing `hash` to a subscript for the array.

You can rest assured that in *every* implementation of `HashMap` or `ConcurrentHashMap` there is some code that reduces the hash code to a number that is suitable for use as a subscript.  It will be there ... somewhere.

But also ... don't expect the code of these classes to be easy to read.  All of the collection classes have been reworked / tuned multiple times get the best possible (average) performance over a wide range of test cases.

Comment: Sorry,my mistake. It seems (n-1) & hash can keep it a positive number.So then  why ConcurrentHashMap do the extra thing?

Comment: Possibly because it needs to.  Possibly this is just an oversight on the part of the author.  You would need to do a forensic analysis of the code to work out which ... which I don't think I can justify doing, myself.  (Hint!)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it handles *negative index* calculations. It's not evident at first looking but there are calculations in some places while accessing the elements(key or value).

`int index =` **`(n - 1) & hash`**, in which `n` is length of the table

It simply handles negative indexing.

AFAIK, `HashMap` always uses arrays sized to a power of 2 (e.g. `16`, `32`, `64`, etc.).

Let's assume we have capacity of `256`(`0x100`) which is `2^8`.
After subtraction 1, we get `256 - 1 = 255` which is `0x100 - 0x1 = 0xFF`
The subtraction gives rise to get the proper bucket index between `0` to `length-1` with exact bit mask needed to bitwise-and with the hash.

```
256 - 1 = 255
0x100 - 0x1 = 0xFF
```

A hash of `260` (`0x104`) gets bitwise-anded with `0xFF` to yield a bucket number of `4`.

A hash of `257` (`0x101`) gets bitwise-anded with `0xFF` to yield a bucket number of `1`.